# Visual Studio Code debugger mapping node_module to local folder

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, aws-sam-cli

I am developing an AWS SAM application in nodejs and have two lambda functions (each are distinct node modules) which both share a third node module which is shared utility functions.

I am using the [install-local](https://www.npmjs.com/package/install-local) npm module to install the shared local utilities node module into the lambda function node modules post-npm-install because SAM local-start doesn't appear to work with symlinked local modules.

This works fine when I start the SAM API locally and hit the end point and I can successfully debug the Lambda functions, however, when I step from the Lambda function code into a function within the shared utilities node module, it opens the file from the lambda function's node_modules directory (local-install doesn't symlink from node_modules to the shared code on my local file system).

I would very much like to somehow map the file in the lambda function's node_modules to the shared utility code on my local file system.

Here is my directory structure:

```
root
  |
  |- LambdaFunction1
    |- app.js
    |- node_modules
      |- SharedUtilityFunctions
        |- app.js
        |- node_modules
  |- LambdaFunction2
    |- app.js
    |- node_modules
      |- SharedUtilityFunctions
        |- app.js
        |- node_modules
  |- SharedUtilityFunctions
    |- app.js
    |- node_modules
```

In this example, I want to (only when debugging in VSCode) map `root/LambdaFunction1/node_modules/SharedUtilityFunctions` to `root/SharedUtilityFunctions`

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Comment: Did you solve the mapping? I'm having the same issue